# How to avoid repeated external calls in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

I'm writing validation for a class (e.g. Car) which requires a number of similar/identical database calls.

```cs
RuleFor(c => c.Id).MustAsync(async (car, id, context, cancellation) => 
{
    return await _carRepository.Get(id) != null;
}).WithMessage("Car with id '{PropertyValue}' does not exist!");

RuleFor(c => c.Model).MustAsync(async (car, model, context, cancellation) => 
{
    var expectedModel = (ModelType)context.ParentContext.RootContextdata["ExpectedModel"]
    var databaseCar = await _carRepository.Get(car.Id); // Repeated database call
    return databaseCar.Model == expectedModel;
}).WithMessage('Stored car does not have the expected model.');
```

Ideally I would do this call once but I gather storing the result as a member on the validator instance is not advised, and overriding `ValidateAsync` with the database result added to the context (similarly to `ExpectedModel` in the example above) results in rather clumsy code to retrieve it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Checking if there is already an item with that ID, in my opinion at least, is NOT validation.

Comment: Car is a property on other objects and I need to validate that the ID that is supplied is genuine - I don't see how that isn't validation?

Comment: I would pass in the Car object into the constructor once I got it from db and call the validator manually when I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick solution could be to add some kind of memoization/caching on your Repository class, so that multiple requests for the same Car within the same context (e.g. HTTP Request) will remember and return the same object without requiring multiple round-trips. But there might be a better way.

There are various levels of validation to consider. As Jammer points out, FluentValidation is usually used to validate the consistency of a given model: did the client send me something that appears on the surface to be a valid request? Determining whether that request is valid given the current state of data is another level of validation that people often do in different ways.

One way that you could get the best of both worlds is to create a new class to represent both the given car model and everything that your application needs in order to validate it.

```
public class ValidCar
{
    public CarModel Model {get; set;}
    public CarEntity Entity {get; set;}
}
```

First you assemble all the data you need into a `new ValidCar`, and then you can use FluentValidation rules on this new model to ensure it's actually valid.

One benefit to this approach is you can have your business logic methods require a `ValidCar` as a parameter instead of just a `CarModel`. This makes it very difficult to accidentally forget to validate the car in some code path, and it prepackages up data that's likely to be useful to much of the business-level logic that you plan to use.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I initially was going to rely on caching but wondered if there was another way - your alternative solution seems very elegant!

Comment: Building on what you have said - we're using data annotations to achieve the model consistency (e.g. a name must be supplied, not be an empty string, etc.), but we have thousands of lines of server-side validation so that meaningful error messages can be returned rather than a unique database constraint violation message for example. I am aiming to organise that code and FluentValidations jumped out as a way of achieving that organisation - perhaps it really isn't a good use-case for it and you have a better suggestion?

Comment: I could only guess because I haven't used FluentValidations at all, and I don't know anything about your code base or your use cases. In the code I write day-to-day, the chances are slim that someone will use the UI to send a request to do something with a "car" that doesn't exist in the database. We don't have people deleting our "cars" on a regular basis. So in those rare cases telling the user "Something went wrong; try refreshing the page." is usually acceptable.

Comment: But if you really do need all that validation code because of the way your app is used, it's possible that FluentValidation can provide a helpful framework for organizing things. Sometimes the best thing to do is to test it on one or two of your models and see how it impacts the behavior and cleanliness of your code.

Comment: I'm working on a rest api which needs to supply more meaningful messages for the applications using it. Again the car is just an example, but examples of this database-'validation' might be checking that the proposed car model name is unique within the database, that the proposed components are in stock, and so on. I don't think that detail changes what you've suggested however. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Put the messages in a RESX and use key lookup in FluentValidation.

Answer (score -1):

I would argue that checking for an existing item with the same ID is not a validation question.

If you have to do this. Create a method in your repository that specifically checks this in an optimised way. Only select the ID column so at least you aren't loading and materialsing the entire entity.

Comment: Okay, ignoring the contrived example using an ID, your suggestion is that I should repeatedly query the database and limit the overhead by reducing the fields being returned?

Comment: No I don't think you should be making data validation dependent on your database at all. I don't advise calling the database from a validator even once let alone multiple times.

Comment: @Jammer: This is not always desirable. Many times you will need to verify data in the database before performing a transaction. Unless you have a streaming data feed straight from the database, the view model you are validating should be considered stale. Check the database each time. However, I have to agree that you don't need to find something by Id just to see if the record exists. This should be handled differently. Either skip that item, or handle this condition closer to the use case.

Comment: @Jammer Okay, so say I have 5 separate lookups to do, I should roll my own validation logic which is essentially identical to that provided by FluentValidation? That's what I was attempting to avoid

Comment: @Greg Burghardt: thanks for your input. I agree, I definitely wouldn't retrieve the object to check it exists. It was just an example aiming to demonstrate multiple rules needing to access a database